# PostgreSQL: Returning the most recent rows grouping by a foreign key column

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table that looks similar to this:

```
credit
+---------+----------------+-------------+--------------+-------------------------+
| id (PK) | person_id (FK) | transaction | total credit |        date_time        |
+---------+----------------+-------------+--------------+-------------------------+
|     345 |              1 |       -1.00 |        34.50 | 2018-08-29 12:00:00.000 |
|     897 |              1 |        5.45 |        39.95 | 2018-08-29 12:34:00.000 |
|     378 |              2 |        0.01 |         0.01 | 2018-08-29 08:00:00.000 |
|     789 |              2 |       20.00 |        20.01 | 2018-08-29 09:00:00.000 |
+---------+----------------+-------------+--------------+-------------------------+
```

How would I write a query in Postgres to return only the most recent (by `date_time DESC`) row grouped by each unique `person_id` in the table, like this?

```
+---------+----------------+-------------+--------------+-------------------------+
| id (PK) | person_id (FK) | transaction | total credit |        date_time        |
+---------+----------------+-------------+--------------+-------------------------+
|     897 |              1 |        5.45 |        39.95 | 2018-08-29 12:34:00.000 |
|     789 |              2 |       20.00 |        20.01 | 2018-08-29 09:00:00.000 |
+---------+----------------+-------------+--------------+-------------------------+
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `distinct on`:

```
select distinct on (person_id) t.*
from t
order by person_id, date_time desc
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this.
use `ROW_NUMBER` with window function to make row number split by person_id  and order by `date_time`  in subquery then get row number is `1`

```
CREATE TABLE credit(
   id int,
   person_id int,
   transaction float,
   "total credit" float,
   date_time timestamp
);

INSERT INTO credit values (345,1 ,-1.00,34.50, '2018-08-29 12:00:00.000');
INSERT INTO credit values (897,1 ,5.45 ,39.95, '2018-08-29 12:34:00.000');
INSERT INTO credit values (378,2 ,0.01 ,0.01 , '2018-08-29 08:00:00.000');
INSERT INTO credit values (789,2 ,20.00,20.01, '2018-08-29 09:00:00.000');
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY person_id  ORDER BY date_time DESC) rn
    FROM credit
) t1
where rn = 1
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/05202/1/0)**:

```
|  id | person_id | transaction | total credit |            date_time | rn |
|-----|-----------|-------------|--------------|----------------------|----|
| 897 |         1 |        5.45 |        39.95 | 2018-08-29T12:34:00Z |  1 |
| 789 |         2 |          20 |        20.01 | 2018-08-29T09:00:00Z |  1 |
```

Comment: Thanks very much for the detailed example!

Comment: @ty2k No problem glad to help